# How to create a controller in Web Api to update the lucene.net index?

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, controller, lucene.net

I'm creating a lucene.net for search engine in web api ,and i want to update the index and create a POST controller to return the update method,and here s the update method for index:

```
 private void QueueToIndex(object para)
    {
        while (true)
        {
            if (bookQueue.Count > 0)
            {
                CRUDIndex();
            }
            else
            {
                Thread.Sleep(3000);
            }
        }
    }
private void CRUDIndex()
{
    Video_List video = new Video_List();

    FSDirectory directory = FSDirectory.Open(new DirectoryInfo(Path), new 
NativeFSLockFactory());
    bool isExist = IndexReader.IndexExists(directory);
    if (isExist)
    {
        if (IndexWriter.IsLocked(directory))
        {
            IndexWriter.Unlock(directory);
        }
    }
    IndexWriter writer = new IndexWriter(directory, new PanGuAnalyzer(), 
!isExist, IndexWriter.MaxFieldLength.UNLIMITED);
    while (bookQueue.Count > 0)
    {
        Document document = new Document();
        BookViewMode book = bookQueue.Dequeue();
        if (book.IT == IndexType.Insert)
        {
            document.Add(new Field("id", book.ID.ToString(), 
Field.Store.YES, Field.Index.NOT_ANALYZED));
            document.Add(new Field("title", book.Title, Field.Store.YES, 
Field.Index.ANALYZED,

Field.TermVector.WITH_POSITIONS_OFFSETS));
            document.Add(new Field("content", book.Starring, 
Field.Store.YES, Field.Index.ANALYZED,

Field.TermVector.WITH_POSITIONS_OFFSETS));
            writer.AddDocument(document);
        }
        else if (book.IT == IndexType.Delete)
        {
            writer.DeleteDocuments(new Term("id", book.ID.ToString()));
        }
        else if (book.IT == IndexType.Modify)
        {

            writer.DeleteDocuments(new Term("id", book.ID.ToString()));
            document.Add(new Field("id", book.ID.ToString(), 
Field.Store.YES, Field.Index.NOT_ANALYZED));
            document.Add(new Field("title", book.Title, Field.Store.YES, 
Field.Index.ANALYZED,

Field.TermVector.WITH_POSITIONS_OFFSETS));
            document.Add(new Field("content", book.Starring, 
Field.Store.YES, Field.Index.ANALYZED,

Field.TermVector.WITH_POSITIONS_OFFSETS));
            writer.AddDocument(document);
        }
    }
    writer.Dispose();
    directory.Dispose();
}
```

So How can i return this method to controller like:

```
private bool Update(BookViewMode model)
    {
        return ;
     }
```